# Quick Fourier Series help?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, fourier-series, signal-processing

[image]

I was given a graph (shown above) and was asked to represent this as a Fourier Series. I was able to solve $a_0$ with no problem. However, when I was integrating for $a_n$ and $b_n$, I was having a little trouble.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*} \frac{\pi a_n}{2} &= \int_0^\pi e^{-t/2} \cos nt\,dt = \int_0^\pi e^{-t/2} \frac{e^{in t} + e^{-int}}{2}\,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi \exp \left( \left(-\frac{1}{2} + in \right) t \right)\,dt + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi \exp \left( \left(-\frac{1}{2} - in \right) t \right)\,dt \\
\end{align*}$$
The first part can be integrated by
$$\int_0^\pi \exp \left( \left(-\frac{1}{2} + in \right) t \right)\,dt
= \frac{1}{-1/2 + in} \left. \exp \left( \left(-\frac{1}{2} + in \right) t \right) \right|_0^\pi = \frac{e^{-\pi/2 + i n \pi} - 1}{-1/2 + in}
$$

Comment: Great answer. Thank you! I'm assuming that sin(nt) would be complex conjugate for $b_n$

Comment: @KingDuken It might not be...

Comment: Henry W, oops, yes. I forgot there was an $i$ in front of the exponents.